# How to show that a database design is in 3rd Normal Form

Tags: database-design

How can I prove that my database schema actually is in 3rd normal form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database is in 3NF if you meet the rules of 1NF, 2NF and 3NF.

As a rough guide.

1. Have no duplicate data in a single row. (columns where the same data is displayed in different way)
2. Eliminate data subsets that are recurring multiple times (I think of this as 'reference' data such as lookups. Things like CustomerRelationshipType)
3. Remove any data that is not directly related to the key of the table (This is a check to ensure that you're not carrying anything unnecessarily or possibly storing something in the wrong table).

Answer (score 3):

Does any non-key field depend on another field that is not part of the key? If so, then the schema is not in 3NF.

Comment: this is still 1NF. if it depends on WHOLE keys, it is only 2NF

Comment: No he is right, copied from wikipedia: "Requiring that non-key attributes be dependent on "the whole key" ensures that a table is in 2NF; further requiring that non-key attributes be dependent on "nothing but the key" ensures that the table is in 3NF."

Answer (score 1):

If all non key attributes are dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, then it should be in third normal form.

Of course, atomicity is already assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Your Database is in 3NF if and only if it follow any one or both of below rules:

Rule 1 : For Each given FD's , Left Hand Side(LHS) of FD should be Superkey for any table in Database.

**OR**

Rule 2 : For Each given FD's , Right Hand Side (RHS) of FD should be Prime Attribute for the ant Relation / Table.

For more detail about Superkey , Prime Attribute etc, Please refer : [Detailed explanation of Normal forms and Database.](http://ashishparihargatenotes.blogspot.in/2016/03/database-management-system-best-one.html)